# Exception dispatching input event- NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-activity

```
04-19 13:00:01.441    2331-2331/com.example.barun.myapplication E/InputEventReceiver﹕ Exception dispatching input event.
04-19 13:00:01.442    2331-2331/com.example.barun.myapplication E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
04-19 13:00:01.442    2331-2331/com.example.barun.myapplication E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.hasSubMenu()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onTouchEvent(ActionMenuItemView.java:135)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2314)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1692)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2739)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2275)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8578)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4021)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3887)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5701)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5675)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5646)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5791)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
04-19 13:00:01.442    2331-2331/com.example.barun.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-19 13:00:01.442    2331-2331/com.example.barun.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.barun.myapplication, PID: 2331
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.hasSubMenu()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onTouchEvent(ActionMenuItemView.java:135)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2314)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1692)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2739)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2275)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8578)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4021)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3887)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5701)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5675)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5646)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5791)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
04-19 13:00:03.580    2331-2331/com.example.barun.myapplication I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 2331 SIG: 9
```

I am learning Android app development following [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjHYyAJQ7Vw&list=PL2F07DBCDCC01493A&index=21) video tutorial, which is basically listing all my app activity extending *ListActivity* class. Following that instructions, I got this error whenever I am selecting an activity from list, app gets thrashed by saying "Unfortunately, My Application has been stopped". 
Searched a lot on stackoverflow, but no question regarding this kind of NullException error

> 'boolean android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.hasSubMenu()' on a null object reference

Below is my code,

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity {
    String classes[] = {"MainActivity","example1","example2","example3","example4","example5","example6"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,R.layout.abc_action_menu_item_layout ,classes));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String cheese = classes[position];

        try {
            Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.barun.myapplication."+cheese);
            Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this,ourClass);
            startActivity(ourIntent);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know any further information required. Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at this line

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,R.layout.abc_action_menu_item_layout, classes));
```

you are using this view `android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView` from `abc_action_menu_item_layout` for your values. ActionBarRelated stuff.

**Solution :** 
Instead create one layout (TextView) set view id to `@android:id/text1`

simple_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Create adapter like this

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, R.layout.simple_ayout, classes));
```

Answer (score 0):

Null Pointer Exception error means something you are doing is returning a 'null' value.

Check your log carefully, you can see that the log tells you that your error is at line 135, at class called `ActionMenuItemView.java`.

`(ActionMenuItemView.java:135)`

Can you give me the code you write in that line?

Something there is probably wrong.

Comment: One moment i taught the same what you taught. :) actually that is API code, look closely the package name of that class `android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onTouchEvent(ActionMenuItemView.java:135)`   :(  : (